# Does browser prefetching have an impact on stats from Google Analytics?

Tags: seo, google-analytics

Some pages can be prefetched by the browser (see [this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#link-type-prefetch) or [that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83656/wordpress-tries-to-load-next-page-after-done-loading-current-page)). If a user uses a browser that prefetches pages, will this be counted by Google Analytics? If there are 5 pages to be prefetched, will Google Analytics count that as 5 visits?

Answer (score 2):

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325769/does-html5-link-prefetch-affect-google-analytics):

> The prefetch only downloads the resources, but does not execute the
>   code, or fire DOM events or so.
>
> Given Google Analytics depends on running JS, I don't expect it to be
>   affected.
>
> Any server side analytics that track requests to the given resources
>   will be affected though.

Comment: I have found only guess on this question throughout the web. This answer on SO is one of them. He "don't expect" it.

Comment: @Cedric: This answer is not a guess - it is a very reasonable assumption based on the information available.